# como enviar objetos de angularjs a un controlador C#

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

buenos dias soy nuevo con angular, tengo problemas para mandar un objeto de angularjs a controlador C#, eh podido mandar un string pero ala hora de querer mandar un objeto me manda error alguien alguna sugerencia el codigo es el siguiente

controladorangularjs

```
 ClaveTruper = "CTF-1/2";
                Descripcion = "Cinta de teflon 1/2";
                Precio ="$4"
                PrecioEspecial ="$2"
                PrecioFabrica ="$3"
                Xml = obj2.Xml;
                CapacidadGancho ="G30"
                CodigoProducto = "12520";
                var ntl = [ CodigoProducto, ClaveTruper, Descripcion, Precio, PrecioEspecial, PrecioFabrica, Xml, CapacidadGancho ];
               // debugger;
                ImprimirService.Impre(ntl)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        if (response.code = 100) {
                            //  $scope.skuis = "";
                            $scope.impri = response.data.Result;

                            // $scope.skuis = Json.parse(angular.toJson(response.data.Result));
                            // console.log($scope.skuis);
                            $scope.impri = angular.fromJson($scope.impre);
                            //console.log($scope.skuis);

                            $scope.apply;


                            }
                        }, function (err) { });

                    return $scope.impri;
```

servicio angular

```
'use strict'
app.service('ImprimirService', ['$http', '$q', '$window', function ($http, $q, $window) {
    this.Impre = function (etiqueta) {
        var defered = $q.defer();

        console.log("Entrando al Servicio Enviar datos para Imprimir")
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'Labels/Impre',
            params: {
                'etiqueta': JSON.stringify(etiqueta)
            },
             dataType:'json'
            //params:{Itemcode:itemcode}

        })
            .then(function (response) {
                defered.resolve(response);
            },
            function (err) {
                defered.reject(err);
            });

        return defered.promise;

    }
}]);
```

controlador c#

```
  [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Impre(Imprimir etiqueta)
        {

            CentralPOSDataManager Code = new CentralPOSDataManager();
            var result = Code.Imprimir(etiqueta);
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

public MethodResponse<Imprimir> Imprimir(Imprimir etiqueta)
        {


            MethodResponse<Imprimir> Result = new MethodResponse<Imprimir>() { Code = 100, Message = "Impresion Exitosa", Result = new Imprimir() };
            try
            {
               var ClaveTruper = "CTF-1/2";
                var Descripcion = "Cinta de teflon 1/2";
                var Precio = "$4";
                var PrecioEspecial = "$2";
                var PrecioFabrica = "$3";
                var Xml = "";//'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ThermalLabel Version="7.0" Width="60" Height="49" GapLength="3" MarkLength="0" OffsetLength="0" UnitType="Mm" LabelsPerRow="1" LabelsHorizontalGapLength="0" IsContinuous="False" PrintSpeed="" PrintMirror="False" CutAfterPrinting="False" ><Items><TextItem Name="Precio" Y="26" DataField="Precio" DataFieldFormatString="" CacheItemId="" Comments="" Tag="" Width="60" Height="15" Text="_x0024__x0020_1_x002C_495" Font="Arial,42,True,False,False,False,Point,,,False,90,,CP850" TextAlignment="Center" CultureName="en-US" /><TextItem Name="Descripcion" X="1" Y="6" DataField="Descripcion" DataFieldFormatString="" CacheItemId="" Comments="" Tag="" Width="57" Height="20" Text="Despachador_x0020_de_x0020_brocas_x0020_de_x0020_alta_x0020_velocidad_x0020_29_x0020_piezas" Font="Arial,16,Point,,,False,90,,CP850" TextAlignment="Center" CultureName="en-US" /><TextItem Name="CodigoProducto" X="1" Y="2" DataField="CodigoProducto" DataFieldFormatString="" CacheItemId="" Comments="" Tag="" Width="20" Height="4" Text="_x0031_4351" Font="Arial Black,9,Point,,,False,90,,CP850" TextAlignment="Justify" CultureName="en-US" /><TextItem Name="ClaveTruper" X="37.9686334474495" Y="2" DataField="ClaveTruper" DataFieldFormatString="" CacheItemId="" Comments="" Tag="" Width="20" Height="4" Text="DESP-BAV-29C" Font="Arial Black,9,Point,,,False,90,,CP850" TextAlignment="Right" CultureName="en-US" /><TextItem Name="PrecioEspecial" X="1" Y="44" DataField="PrecioEspecial" DataFieldFormatString="" CacheItemId="" Comments="" Tag="" Width="29" Height="4" Text="Especial_x0020_1_x002C_495" Font="Arial,9,Point,,,False,90,,CP850" CultureName="en-US" /><TextItem Name="PrecioFabrica" X="30" Y="44" DataField="PrecioFabrica" DataFieldFormatString="" CacheItemId="" Comments="" Tag="" Width="28" Height="4" Text="Fábrica_x0020_1_x002C_150" Font="Arial,9,Point,,,False,90,,CP850" TextAlignment="Right" CultureName="en-US" /><TextItem Name="CapacidadGancho" X="21.4641520797575" Y="1.95020953998517" DataField="CapacidadGancho" DataFieldFormatString="" CacheItemId="" Comments="" Tag="" Width="16.0243443647563" Height="4" Text="G8" Font="Arial Black,9,Point,,,False,90,,CP850" TextAlignment="Center" CultureName="en-US" /></Items></ThermalLabel >'; 
                var CapacidadGancho = "G30";
                var CodigoProducto = "12520";
               // Arr ntl = etiqueta;//[ CodigoProducto, ClaveTruper, Descripcion, Precio, PrecioEspecial, PrecioFabrica, Xml, CapacidadGancho ];
                var tl = Neodynamic.SDK.Printing.ThermalLabel.CreateFromXmlTemplate(etiqueta.Xml.ToString());
                using (PrintJob pj = new PrintJob())
                {

                    PrinterSettings myPrinter = new PrinterSettings();

                        myPrinter.ProgrammingLanguage = ProgrammingLanguage.EPL;


                    pj.PrinterSettings = myPrinter;
                    pj.Print(tl);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Result.Message = ex.Message + "METODO RESPONDE DE ETIQUETAS";
            }
            return Result;
        }
```

espero alguien pueda darme una  solucion u.u gracias

Comment: Hola, para poder responderte necesitaría ver la definición de la clase Imprimir (la que recibe como parámetro el método Impre del controlador MVC). Lo que sí debes saber es que no puedes enviar un array a un método que espera un objeto de una determinada clase, porque lo que hace el ModelBinder para llenar los valores de las propiedades es, a groso modo y muy simplicado, usar reflection y buscar los nombres de las propiedades en el cuerpo del post para rellenarlas. Ahora te estará dando error porque no encuentra ningún método que corresponda con el tipo de parámetros que el envias.

Comment: esta es mi clase base

Comment: public class ImpresionMtxt
    {
                      public string Accion { set; get; }
        public string TipoImpresion { set; get; }
        public string SKUinicial { get; set; }
        public string SKUFinal { set; get; }
        public string ListaTda { set; get; }
        public string ListaMay { set; get; }
        public string PorPieza { set; get; }
        public string ConPrecio { set; get; }
        public string Impresora { set; get; }
        public string labels { set; get; }
        public string ListaPrecios { set; get; }
    }

Comment: otra clase que recibe los datos

Comment: public  class ImpresionTxt
    {
        
       public List<ImpresionMtxt> etiqueta { get; set; }
        public ImpresionTxt() { etiqueta = new List<ImpresionMtxt>(); }
    }

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta el el binding que realiza por defecto MVC.

Cuando tienes un metodo HttpPost o HttpPut y recibe un tipo simple(int,string,...) por defecto se obtiene de la url. En el caso de tipos complejos se obtienen del body de la petición. Si deseamos que un tipo simple se reciba desde el cuerpo de la petición hay que decorar el parámetro con la etiqueta [FromBody]

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Labels/Impre")]
public JsonResult Impre([FromBody]Imprimir etiqueta){
}
```

y el servicio de angular

```
  $http.post('/Labels/Impre', etiqueta)
```

Comment: trate de hacer lo que me sugeriste, pero la lista que mando de angular nunca llega  al controller de C# , ya cree una clase que la reciba desde el controlador, pero por alguna razon nunca llega

Comment: He editado mi respuesta, con ese código me funciona correctamente, si no te funciona, publica tu clase Imprimir, a ver si damos con el error

Comment: fijate que la unica forma qu epude hacerlo es mediante un controlador api, ya que el controllador mvc nunca me llegaba el objeto.